# Combinatorica Functionality in Vers. 11.1.1

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees, combinatorica, compatibility

Since version 10, much of the original functionality in the Combinatorica package has been subsumed (consumed?) by new graph primitive functions. However, as per similar posts, at times there are conflicts.

As I am interested in better understanding graph encoding, I wish to investigate properties of different potential encodings.  One simple/direct encoding is via Prüfer sequences.  The Combinatorica package had two functions (one the inverse of the other) LabeledTreeToCode[] and CodeToLabeledTree[] to encode/decode the bijection between Prüfer codes and their graphs.  However, simply using the following for a simple graph fail to instantiate, generating a general error that Combinatorica and permutation functions may be conflicting (which presumably they are).

```
 totalOrder = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}]

 Needs[Combinatorica`]  

 LabeledTreeToCode[totalOrder]

 CodeToLabeledTree[totalOrder]
```

If I create the graph after calling Combinatorica` I get a series of errors (Table, Join, General) finally suppressing output.

How can I obtain the original functionality of these two functions from within Vers. 11.1.1?  Or, is there a way within Vers. 11.1.1 to obtain this functionality without calling the old Combinatorica code?

Comment: Use `Block[{$ContextPath}, Needs["Combinatorica\`"]]` to load, then when you want a *conbinatorica* function, preface function name with Combinatorica'. In general, internal representations are not interchangeable, that is, a MMA graph object won't work with Combinatorica and vice-versa.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you defined the `Graph` using M syntax and not `Combinatorica` syntax. For your example you should do:

```
g = Combinatorica`Graph[{{{1,2}},{{2,3}}}, {1,2,3}]
```

> Combinatorica`Graph[{{{1, 2}}, {{2, 3}}}, {1, 2, 3}]

Then, you can use the `Combinatorica` functions:

```
code = Combinatorica`LabeledTreeToCode[g]
Combinatorica`CodeToLabeledTree[code]
```

> {2}
>
> Combinatorica`Graph[{{{1, 2}}, {{2, 3}}}, {{{-0.4999999999999998, 
>     0.8660254037844387}}, {{-0.5000000000000004, -0.8660254037844384}}, {{
>      1., 0}}}]

Comment: I think that should be `FromUnorderedPairs[{{1,2}, {2,3}}]`. ``Graph[{{{1,2}},{{2,3}}}, {1,2,3}]`` creates an invalid graph in Combinatorica. The second argument should be a list of vertex coordinates associated with options, e.g. `{{{0,0}}, {{1,0}}, {{2,0}}}`. I think `Graph` is not meant to be used as a constructor in Combinatorica.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently, they killed it off without making an equivalent, so you'd have to re-implement an algorithm.

documentation link is here: [Upgrading from: Combinatorica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/Combinatorica.html)

> In some cases, parameterized variants have not yet been implemented in the Wolfram System, but a subset can be found in GraphData.
>
> ...

So you'll have to make your own.

This should work as the tree-to-code to produce a Prüfer sequence:

```
TreeToCode[g_Graph?(TreeGraphQ@# &)] := Block[{tempTree = g, res = {}},
  While[VertexCount@tempTree > 2,
    With[
      {leastLeaf = Sort[{VertexDegree[tempTree,#],#}&/@VertexList@tempTree][[1,2]]},
      AppendTo[res, AdjacencyList[tempTree,leastLeaf][[1]]];
      tempTree = VertexDelete[tempTree,leastLeaf];
  ]];
  Return[res]];

totalOrder = Graph[{4<->1, 4<->2, 4<->3, 4<->5, 5<->6}];
sample = Graph[{1<->2, 1<->3, 4<->1, 2<->6, 3<->5, 3<->7, 5<->8}];
TreeToCode[totalOrder]
TreeToCode[sample]
TreeToCode[Graph[{1<->2, 2<->3}]]
```

Out:

```
{4, 4, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5}
{2}
```

Code-to-Tree shouldn't be too difficult to recreate as well. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence) has a procedural implementation, but there's a functional way to get it done in MMA.

Sorry that I don't have better news for you.

Answer (score 2):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) already has replacements for most graph-related Combinatorica functions that are not yet covered by built-in functionality.

Since IGraph/M 0.3.98, you can use `IGFromPrufer` to convert a Prüfer sequence to a tree. The reverse operation is planned for a future version. Until it is added, you can use [Gregory Klopper's implementation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144873/12).

```
IGFromPrufer[{4, 4, 4, 5}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

To convert it back, use

```
IGToPrufer[%]
(* {4, 4, 4, 5} *)
```

`IGToPrufer` is available since v0.3.109.