# Problem with the Needs function on Mathematica 11.1

Tags: packages

I wrote code on Mathematica 11.1 where I need to use the function `Needs` to partitions of integers and Young tableaus, but when I run the following lines:

```
IntervalSlider; 
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
```

I get this problem:

```
Needs::nocont: Context Combinatorica` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144868/combinatorica-functionality-in-vers-11-1-1

Comment: Does it happen if this is the only thing you run after restarting the kernel (`Quit[]`)?  If yes, try disabling the suggestions bar in the preferences (this is a shot in the dark). Does that help?